# Getting error while trying to run xml file in testNG

Tags: selenium-webdriver

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "https://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd" >
<suite name="Test Suite" verbose="2">
<Test name="Test Cases">
<CLASSES>
<CLASS name="testNG.DependencyMgmt"></CLASS>
<CLASS name="testNG.Orderoftestcase"></CLASS>
<CLASS name="testNG.Sampletestcase"></CLASS>
<CLASS name="testNG.SkipTestCase"></CLASS>
</CLASSES>
</Test>
</suite>
```

On running the above code getting the below error:

```
Multiple annotations found at this line:
    - The content of element type "suite" must match "(groups?,listeners|packages|test|parameter|
     method-selectors|suite-files)*)".
    - The content of element type "suite" must match "(groups?,listeners|packages|test|parameter|
     method-selectors|suite-files)*)".
```

Please help to resolve the same.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing `Test` to `test`, also `CLASSES` to `classes`, `CLASS` to `class`
so every tag name is lowercase